# Flutter Permission denied, errno = 13 PlatformException(UsbSerialPortAdapter, Failed to acquire USB device., null, null)

Tags: flutter, dart, serial-port, usbserial, dart-communications

I am developing a Flutter app that needs to access a USB device. I have added the necessary permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file, like the next:

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.permission.USB_PERMISSION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I also added the next in the mainfest file:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
```

I am using `usb_serial: ^0.4.0` package to make the connection process.
I have also tried to download a fully working Flutter project that uses a USB communication, but it gave me the same error, so its now something related to the project rather than being related to the Android platform. another part of the error was like this:
 `Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.usb.UsbUserPermissionManager .checkPermission(UsbUserPermissionManager.java:741)`
so can anyone help me to solve it?

I have tried to take permission from the user, but non of the permission lines that I added were giving any popup message to the user, and I couldn't take the user's permission.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the "Connection Failure with Android 13 Plugin" error by including the following in my pubspec.yaml file:

```yaml
dependencies:
    usb_serial: ^0.5.1
```

This addition fixed the issue for me.